# Rails sorting result from group(..).sum(..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails and graphing some data. I use the following:

```
<%= column_chart User.includes(:levels).group(:email).sum(:score) %>
```

How do i make this group command sort the returned array by score from highest to lowest?

My models are arranged as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  contains id, email
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels
  belongs_to :user
  #contains id, user_id, name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  #contains id, score and game_id
end
```

Comment: Did you try `User.includes(:levels).group(:email).order("score ASC").sum(:score)` ?

Comment: Yeah it cannot be done like that, probably because the score is not yet summed up at the order(...)

Comment: Hm, how about `User.select("SUM(score)").includes(:levels).group(:email).order("score ASC")` ?

Comment: nah, doesnt work, in my case: score is not part of the user but the level... so i want to sum the score from all levels related to an email and then sort this based on the sum...

Comment: `User.select("SUM(levels.score)").includes(:levels).group("users.email").order("levels.score ASC")` ?

Comment: User.select("SUM(levels.score)").includes(:levels).group("users.email").order("‌​levels.score DESC") .. from highest to lowest so DESC

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your `score` in `Level` or in `User` ?
OK, they're in a deeper nested relation.

You can make your life easier, if your `User` model declares that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  has_many :levels, through: :games
end
```

Then you have to `join` the levels.

Looking at the SQL generated by ActiveRecord, you can see that

```
User.joins(:levels).group(:email).sum(:score)
```

generates

```
SELECT sum(score) AS sum_score, email FROM users INNER JOIN games ON games.user_id = users.id INNER JOIN levels ON levels.games_id=games.id GROUP BY email
```

As `sum` doesn't return a `Relation`, but an `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`, you cannot append `.order()` to it.
What you can do, is inject the `order` before the sum:

```
User.joins(:levels).group(:email).order('sum_score DESC').sum(:score)
```

generates

```
SELECT sum(score) AS sum_score, email FROM users 
   INNER JOIN games ON games.user_id = users.id 
   INNER JOIN levels ON levels.games_id=games.id 
  GROUP BY email 
  ORDER BY sum_score DESC
```

which is, what you are looking for.

Comment: That is a wicked answer.  Thanks.  For those wanting to put a limit() in there, put it after the order(...), before the sum.  Shame that AREL can't handle putting things in the proper order.  Putting the 'order' before the sum that creates the thing being ordered (and having to find that in SQL output to know what to call it) is quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree that it's counter-intuitive. It helps to look at `sum` as similar to `pluck`. It ends the AREL chain and starts using arrays and hashes. So everything that should go to the SQL aka AREL has to be before the `sum`.